# How to call default method of interface in groovy Class

Tags: java, groovy

I have groovy class Page which implements a interface named IImageOperations.

This interface contain a default method addImage. Which i wanted to call from Page class.

I tried to call in below manner

```
class Page implements IImageOperations, ITextOperations {

void addImage(PDImageXObject image, float x, float y, float w = 0, float h = 0, float rotate = 0, boolean inline){
    if(w == 0)
        w = image.getWidth();
    if(h == 0)
        h = image.getHeight();
    IImageOperations.super.addImage("", 0, 0);
}
}
```

But, it is giving me below error

**Groovy:The usage of 'Class.this' and 'Class.super' is only allowed in nested/inner classes.**

If we define this Page class as Java Class, then things are working fine.

Comment: Have you tried simply `addImage("", 0, 0)`?

Comment: Please provide how do you declare your class.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak, Yes, i tried it, still eclipse is showing error

Comment: @daggett -- Added complete groovy class

Comment: @daggett -- Thanks for your help. Seems like we can use it directly, without super. Eclipse is showing false error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following correct java code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;


public class A implements Type{
    public static void main(String [] arg){
        new A().run();
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println( Type.super.getTypeName() );
    }

}
```

failed to compile under groovy:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
A.groovy: 10: The usage of 'Class.this' and 'Class.super' is only allowed in nested/inner classes.
 @ line 10, column 23.
                System.out.println( Type.super.getTypeName() );
```

however the following syntax works fine (groovy 2.4.11):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class A implements Type{
    public static void main(String [] arg){
        new A().run();
    }

    public void run(){
        //System.out.println( Type.super.getTypeName() );
        System.out.println( ((Type)this).getTypeName() );
    }

}
```